# Batch returns "ECHO IS OFF" when looking for variable value

Tags: batch-file

So I've created a script to check for certain folders / file paths, it does this fine, during the check if the folder is found, it changes the value of a variable to "found". If the folder isn't found, it leaves the value to the default "NA". However when returning to the menu where it displays the value, all it returns is "ECHO IS OFF". First I tried saving them to a log file, but it refused to save them. I'm guessing this is also preventing me from viewing the values.

I've already tried adding "IF NOT" to make sure it isn't hitting a missing folder then refusing to set values, but that's all I can think of.

Here's a snippet of code.

During the check:

```
IF EXIST System\SystemCore set SC= Found
IF EXIST System\SystemCore\4BIOS set SC4B= Found
IF EXIST System\SystemCore\4BIOS\Default set SC4BD= Found
goto :DCV
```

after this, the menu where the values are displayed:

```
:DCV
echo %SC%
echo %SC4B%
echo %SC4BD%
echo %SC4BB%
echo %SC4BOK%
echo %SCCAGOL%
echo %SCCAGOLG%
echo %SCCAE%
echo %SSST%
echo %CLB%
echo %ITC%
echo %SSSTF%
echo %UPF%
echo %SUU%
echo %UUTF%
```

I went into this not expecting ANY errors, but here we are.
There are no errors such as "system cannot find ...etc"

Comment: If you want a space in your output you should enclose values in quotes. `IF EXIST System\SystemCore set "SC= Found"`..

Comment: And, you probably want it to be something like `IF EXIST System\SystemCore set "SC=SC Found"`

Comment: It should be this syntax, `IF EXIST "System\SystemCore\" Set "SC=Found"` and `echo=%SC%`. The **`=`** in `echo=` can be one of many characters, but from tests it was found that **`(`**, **`=`** and **`/`** were more robust than the commonly used **`.`**. Additionally you have stated that you've already pre-defined all of those variables with a value of `NA`, which means that you've either not done so correctly, or you've done so within the same parenthesised block of code, without enabling delayed variable expansion. Can you please post the code from the point you set those variables?

Comment: @Compo The values are set when the script is launched, and I've started to see my error here, although setting values like this has worked for me before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, during testing I was starting the integcheck.bat from itself and giving the full directory paths it would need if called from by OS4 or 4BIOS, after calling from either one, it works correctly. Although some values do return `ECHO IS OFF`, I'm assuming it's because it's checking the same directory, just one path ahead.

I have learned from my mistakes.

To fix this, call in this order; OS4 -> 4BIOS -> integcheck
Assuming all file paths are correctly set and the values are predefined to be `NA`, everything works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo anything, including possibly an empty line, you can add a '.' between the echo command and the variable, like:

```
echo.%SC%
echo.%SC4B%
echo.%SC4BD%
echo.%SC4BB%
echo.%SC4BOK%
echo.%SCCAGOL%
echo.%SCCAGOLG%
echo.%SCCAE%
echo.%SSST%
echo.%CLB%
echo.%ITC%
echo.%SSSTF%
echo.%UPF%
echo.%SUU%
echo.%UUTF%
```

Comment: Trying this just removes ```"ECHO IS OFF"``` and shows a blank screen, after trying each of the replies the issue still persists.

Comment: The `echo.` variant has some drawbacks, better use `echo(`, looks odd but works better [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ..](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774#p4554)

Answer (score 1):

Without even discussing the other factors such as the whitespace in your code, you can simply revert to `if defined` to test if the variable has a value and only if it does will it `echo` This example does it in a for loop for each variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (SC SC4B SC4BD SC4BB SC4BOK SCCAGOL SCCAGOLG SCCAE SSST CLB ITC SSSTF UPF SUU UUTF) do if defined %%i echo !%%i!
```